# Chrome mediaelement.js stream and download link conflict

Tags: google-chrome, media-player, audio-streaming, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

I'm having trouble getting audio streams and download links (for the same file) to play nice on a page in Chrome.

http://500mixes.com

For each audio file, I have a separate player and download link. The player is mediaelement.js. The **problem** is that clicking on the download button stops the stream. But the opposite (download, then stream) works fine.

I know one solution would be to use a modal pop-up to pull the download link out of the page. But I'm hoping to find an inline solution. Does mediaelement.js have native download functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at your code yet, so this assumes you aren't doing anything strange...

If you link to a download, the browser will often begin the process of shutting down the current page in order to go to the next page.  This is a reasonable optimization, since most links are pointing to other pages, not downloads.

To get around this, set the target of your download links to `_blank`.  This opens the download link in a new window.  Note that a simple modal dialog on the same page will not work.  You must set the target to somewhere else.

Alternatively, add a hidden `<iframe>` to your page and set the target of those download links to it.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same problem, the download link shows but is not clickable. Simply adding target="_blank" within the URL makes the link clickable and makes the file downloadable. Thanks.